# How to use sed to isolate linux fingerprint in output of "ssh-keygen -if"

Tags: awk, sed, ssh, fingerprinting

I need to isolate the ssh fingerprint on a linux box with code. I can run ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub to get it:

```
[root@foo ssh]# ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
2048 11:11:11:11:11:blah:blah /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub (RSA)
```

I can pipe that to sed to get rid of the 2048 bit:

```
[root@foo ssh]# ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub | sed 's/2048 //g'
11:11:11:11:11:blah:blah /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub (RSA)
```

But I'm left with the filepath (RSA) bit at the end. I want to add another piped sed command, but I'm having trouble with the /'s.

Answer (score 3):

If you just like `11:11:11:11:11:blah:blah`  try:

```
[root@foo ssh]# ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Perfect, gets what I want exactly. Thank you sir!

Comment: @Sly_Boots You are welcome.  If you like this answer, please accept it :)